# Python list comprehension for dictionaries in dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I just learned about list comprehension, which is a great fast way to get data in a single line of code. But something's bugging me.

In my test I have this kind of dictionaries inside the list:

```
[{'y': 72, 'x': 94, 'fname': 'test1420'}, {'y': 72, 'x': 94, 'fname': 'test277'}]
```

The list comprehension `s = [ r for r in list if r['x'] > 92 and r['x'] < 95 and r['y'] > 70 and r['y'] < 75 ]` works perfectly on that (it is, in fact, the result of this line)

Anyway, I then realised I'm not really using a list in my other project, I'm using a dictionary. Like so:

```
{'test1420': {'y': '060', 'x': '070', 'fname': 'test1420'}}
```

That way I can simply edit my dictionary with `var['test1420'] = ...`

But list comprehensions don't work on that!
And I can't edit lists this way because you can't assign an index like that.

Is there another way?

Comment: List comprehensions can be cool, but don't go overboard.  There's no steadfast rule against giant comprehensions, but for what it's worth, Google's Python Style Guide recommends against anything overly complex: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=List_Comprehensions#List_Comprehensions

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do this:

```
s = dict([ (k,r) for k,r in mydict.iteritems() if r['x'] > 92 and r['x'] < 95 and r['y'] > 70 and r['y'] < 75 ])
```

This takes a dict as you specified and returns a 'filtered' dict.

Comment: Works the same way as Tryptich's solution, but using iteritems is indeed faster. Thanks!

Comment: you can make this even faster if you turn `[]` in to `()` as dict can take a generator as an argument (if the generator expression is the only argument like in this case even the `()` can be left out)

Comment: For python3 , use dict.items() instead of dict.iteritems()

Comment: If you don't need to keep the key you can also use `dict.values()` and do a reguler list comprehension on top of that.

Answer (score 10):

If `dct` is

```
{'test1420': {'y': '060', 'x': '070', 'fname': 'test1420'},
 'test277': {'y': 72, 'x': 94, 'fname': 'test277'},}
```

Perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
[ subdct for key,subdct in dct.iteritems() 
  if 92<subdct['x']<95 and 70<subdct['y']<75 ]
```

A little nicety is that Python allows you to chain inequalities:

```
92<dct[key]['x']<95
```

instead of

```
if r['x'] > 92 and r['x'] < 95
```

Note also that above I've written a list comprehension, so you get back a list (in this case, of dicts).

In Python3 there are such things as [dict comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Dict_and_set_comprehensions) as well:

```
{ n: n*n for n in range(5) } # dict comprehension
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
```

In Python2 the equivalent would be

```
dict( (n,n*n) for n in range(5) )
```

I'm not sure if you are looking for a list of dicts or a dict of dicts, but if you understand the examples above, it is easy to modify my answer to get what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
my_dict = {'test1420': {'y': '060', 'x': '070', 'fname': 'test1420'},
           'test277' : {'y': '072', 'x': '094', 'fname': 'test277'}}


new_dict = dict((k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items() 
                    if 92 < int(v['x']) < 95 and 70 < int(v['y']) < 75)
```

Some notes on this code:

1. I'm using a generator expression
   instead of a list comprehension
2. Python lets you combine inequality
   tests as `low < value < high`
3. The dict() constructor takes an iterable
   of key/value tuples to create a
   dictionary

Comment: This works, and looks, the same as adamk's solution. Yet using iteritems is quite a bit faster than this one.

Both er slower than the regular list comprehension, though :P 

Thanks for the combination tip!

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 you can use dict comprehension which can be an even shorter solution:

```
{key_expression(item) : value_expression(item) for item in something if condition}
```

1. In case you want to filter a dictionary as in the original question:

   ```
   mydict = {'test1': {'y':  60},'test2': {'y':  70},'test3': {'y':  80}}
   s = {k : r for k,r in mydict.items() if r['y'] < 75 }
   > {'test1': {'y': 60}, 'test2': {'y': 70}}
   ```
2. Or we can even create something out of a list or range. E.g. if we want a dictionary with all odd square numbers:

   ```
   {i : i**2 for i in range(11) if i % 2 == 1}
   > {1: 1, 3: 9, 5: 25, 7: 49, 9: 81}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the values of a dictionary d with `d.values()`. Your list comprehension should work using that, although I'm a little unclear what exactly you want the output to be.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there another way?**

Why not consider the use of some lightweight objects?

You can *still* use list comprehensions for gathering or filtering the objects, and gain a lot in clarity / extensibility.

```
>>> class Item(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y, name):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...         self.name = name
... 
>>> list_items = []
>>> list_items.append(Item(x=70, y=60, name='test1420'))                        
>>> list_items.append(Item(x=94, y=72, name='test277'))                         
>>> items_matching = [item for item in list_items 
                      if 92 < item.x < 95 and 70 < item.y < 75]
>>> for item in items_matching:
...     print item.name
... 
test277
>>> first_item = items_matching[0]
>>> first_item.x += 50
>>> first_item.x
144
```