# Retrieving values of Numpy arrays stored as values of a dictionary with a list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a python dictionary which values are Numpy arrays. I want to create a list of a specific value of all arrays to find the maximum of them with a `max()` function.
I was thinking about using the following expression which implies a list comprehension :

```
what_I_look_for = max([my_dict[key][0,0] for key in my_dict.keys()])
```

Unfortunately, the above expression raises an `IndexError`. I suspect the `[0,0]` to screw things up. I have been thinking about working around with a [Nested List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) or with an [`my_dict.iteritems()` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231250/python-list-comprehension-for-dictionaries-in-dictionaries) but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are the numpy arrays 2 dimensional?

Comment: Print the dict and show us what you get.

Comment: The dictionary values look like [this](http://pastie.org/8161958).
`.shape` gives `(24,3)` for that one.

Comment: When you state "for that one", it looks like they may have different sizes. So I suggest you print `[my_dict[key].shape for key in my_dict.keys()]` to see if one of them is perhaps a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @bogatron : You are right. They are all 2 dimensional arrays with three rows but some of them have just 1 line.
How can I work around ? With an `try` statement to manage this exception in a for loop ?

Comment: If you are always looking only at the first element of the first row of the array, you could use `my_dict[key].ravel()[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Forgot the `ravel` option.