# Using list comprehension to match values of dictionaries which are stored in lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two lists of dictionaries which I need to compare:

```
search_list =[{'Chr':'chr1','St':'2345','End':'2456'},
              {'Chr':'chr1','St':'3457','End':'4567'}]
```

and

```
database = [{'Chr':'chr1','St':'2348','End':'2348'},
            {'Chr':'chr1','St':'190','End':'190'}]
```

Therefore each dictionary within the list looks like this:

```
{'Chr':'chr1','St':'2345','End':'2456'}
```

Where Chr = Chromosome, St = start coordinate, and End = end coordinate.

I need to identify the values in the database which match on the Chr value and are between the St and End values (which need to be integers, rather than their current string form). From what I can tell list comprehension is the best way to accomplish this. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231250/python-list-comprehension-for-dictionaries-in-dictionaries) has been my conceptual starting point, but I'm a bit confused about how to proceed.

My pseudocode is:

```
matched = [var for var in search_list where search_list['Chr'] == database['Chr'] AND search_list['St'] >= database['St'] <= search_list['End']]
```

But obviously that's very rough! Any suggestions would be most welcome.

**Update** I've tried KobiK's suggestion which looks like it should work. But now am having trouble transforming the values attached to the 'St' and 'End' keys from strings to integers in order to do the mathematical searching.

Here's what I've got:

```
matchedVars ={[record for record in database for lookup in search_list if 
record['Chr'] == lookup['Chr'] if int(lookup['St']) <= int(record['St']) 
<= int(lookup['End'])]}
```

But it throws this error:

> File "snp_freq_V1-4.py", line 86, in
>
> matchedVars ={[record
>   for record in database for lookup in search_list if record['Chr'] ==
>   lookup['Chr'] if int(lookup['St']) <= int(record['St']) <=
>   int(lookup['End'])]}
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Is there a better/more appropriate way to transform keys from strings to ints?

Comment: Can't understand the St and End part, what is the up/low limit

Comment: what database are you using? this seems it could be a query problem? should your `St` and `End` be integers? Is your database an actual database or is it a list called database?

Comment: @dm03514 database is just a list called database. Have updated question to reflect St and End as  you have helpfully pointed out, they should be ints.

Comment: @Kobi K see updated question. They are keys within a dict.

Comment: You have 2 parameters inside database dict and 2 parameters in the search it's not clear....in your example you are doing `search_list['St'] >= database['St'] <= search_list['End']` what about `database['End']` where to use it?

Comment: @KobiK ah yes I see. No I don't need database['End'] as it always matches database['St'], sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @s_boardman you get this exception since one of the strings cannot convert to int, make sure it's only numbers. you can combine a `try except` statement and catch the ones giving you this problem.

Comment: @KobiK thanks! Going to try altering the values on input rather than complicate things further on in my script. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk): 
This code will iterate elemnts in `database` dict and will check for criteria in `search_list`

```
search_list =[{'Chr':'chr1','St':'2345','End':'2456'},{'Chr':'chr2','St':'3457','End':'4567'}]
database = [{'Chr':'chr1','St':'2348','End':'2348'},{'Chr':'chr2','St':'190','End':'190'}]

print [record for record in database for lookup in search_list
       if record['Chr'] == lookup['Chr'] if lookup['St'] <= record['St'] <= lookup['End']]
```

Output:

```
[{'Chr': 'chr1', 'End': '2348', 'St': '2348'}]
```

As you can see in the output only `{'Chr': 'chr1', 'End': '2348', 'St': '2348'}` is matching the criteria's inside the `search_list`

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I've tried it but now have the problem of transforming the values of St and End keys from str to int. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Changed my start point so that this works perfectly. Thanks @KobiK!

Answer (score -1):

This is a rough code, but how about this?

```
matched = []
for d in search_list:
  for db in database:
    if d["Chr"] == db["Chr"]:
      if db["St"] >= d["St"] and db["St"] <= d["End"]:
        matched.append(db)
print matched
```

Hope it will help