# Matching values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two dictionaries which contain nested sub-dictionaries. They are structured as follows:

```
search_regions = {
    'chr11:56694718-71838208': {'Chr': 'chr11', 'End': 71838208, 'Start': 56694718},
    'chr13:27185654-39682032': {'Chr': 'chr13', 'End': 39682032, 'Start': 27185654}
}

database_variants = {
    'chr11:56694718-56694718': {'Chr': 'chr11', 'End': 56694718, 'Start': 56694718},
    'chr13:27185659-27185659': {'Chr': 'chr13', 'End': 27185659, 'Start': 27185659}
}
```

I need to compare them and pull out the dictionaries in database_variants
 which fall in the range of the dictionaries in search_regions.

I am building a function to do this ([linked to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389877/using-list-comprehension-to-match-values-of-dictionaries-which-are-stored-in-lis)). This is what I have so far:

```
def region_to_variant_location_match(search_Variants, database_Variants):
    '''Take dictionaries for search_Variants and database_Variants as input.
    Match variants in database_Variants to regions within search_Variants.
    Return matches as a nested dictionary.'''
    #Match on Chr value
        #Where Start value from database_variant is between St and End values in 
        search_variants.
    #return as nested dictionary
```

The problem I am having is working out how to get to the values in the nested dictionaries (Chr, St, End, etc) for the comparison. I'd like to do this using list comprehension as I've got quite a bit of data to get through so a simpler for loop might be more time consuming.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I've tried to implement the solution suggested by bioinfoboy below. My first step was to convert the search_regions and database_variants dictionaries into defaultdict(list) using the following functions:

```
def search_region_converter(searchDict):
    '''This function takes the dictionary of dictionaries and converts it to a
    DefaultDict(list) to allow matching   
    with the database in a corresponding format'''
    search_regions = defaultdict(list)
    for i in search_regions.keys():
        chromosome = i.split(":")[0]
        start = int(i.split(":")[1].split("-")[0])
        end = int(i.split(":")[1].split("-")[1])
        search_regions[chromosome].append((start, end))
    return search_regions #a list with chromosomes as keys 

def database_snps_converter(databaseDict):
    '''This function takes the dictionary of dictionaries and converts it to a
    DefaultDict(list) to allow matching   
    with the serach_snps in a corresponding format'''
    database_variants = defaultdict(list)
    for i in database_variants.keys():
        chromosome = i.split(":")[0]
        start = int(i.split(":")[1].split("-")[0])
        database_variants[chromosome].append(start)
    return database_variants #list of database variants
```

Then I have made a function for matching (again with bioinfoboy's code), which is as follows:

```
def region_to_variant_location_match(search_Regions, database_Variants):
    '''Take dictionaries for search_Variants and database_Variants as 
    input.                                         
    Match variants in database_Variants to regions within search_Variants.'''
    for key, values in database_Variants.items():
        for value in values:
            for search_area in search_Regions[key]:
                print(search_area)
                if (value >= search_area[0]) and (value <= search_area[1]):
                    yield(key, search_area)
```

However the defaultdict functions return empty dictionaries and I can't quite work out what I need to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is not need to open another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24389877/1982962) and your problem is that you have changed the data format from `list` of `dicts` with a specific format to `dict` of `dicts` with a diffrent format you cannot change the pattern and except the code to work.

Comment: Your code for function `region_to_variant_location_match` is very hard to read and seems to be invalid Python syntax. Reformat it, make it valid Python code, and possibly try to make it conforming to [PEP008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It will take few hours of reading and refactoring, but it will definitely pay back soon.

Comment: @KobiK Having looked into the problem in more detail I realised I needed to have the input as nested dicts, rather than lists of dicts. I thought opening a new question was more appropriate than changing the starting point of the existing one. I will edit to improve the logic.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky thanks Jan, that makes it much better! I'll make sure to use this from now on. I'm going to edit the question slightly which might remove some of your very helpful advice, so just letting you know I appreciate it. :)

Comment: I think you can check out `defaultdict` and modify your `search_regions` such that the keys are chromosomes (eg. `chr11`). After that you can have the start and end as a list of tuples/lists. I have come across similar situations and all I can think of is changing keys to chromosomes. That might not be the best and least time consuming option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this may help

I'm converting your `search_regions` and `database_variants` according to what I've mentioned in the comment.

```python
from collections import defaultdict
_database_variants = defaultdict(list)
_search_regions = defaultdict(list)
for i in database_variants.keys():
    _chromosome = i.split(":")[0]
    _start = int(i.split(":")[1].split("-")[0])
    _database_variants[_chromosome].append(_start)
_search_regions = defaultdict(list)
for i in search_regions.keys():
    _chromosome = i.split(":")[0]
    _start = int(i.split(":")[1].split("-")[0])
    _end = int(i.split(":")[1].split("-")[1])
    _search_regions[_chromosome].append((_start, _end))

def _search(_database_variants, _search_regions):
    for key, values in _database_variants.items():
        for value in values:
            for search_area in _search_regions[key]:
                if (value >= search_area[0]) and (value <= search_area[1]):
                    yield(key, search_area)
```

I've used `yield` and thus would return a generator object on which you can iterate through. Considering the data that you've provided initially in the question, I get the following output.

```
for i in _search(_database_variants, _search_regions):
    print(i)
```

The output is the following:

```
('chr11', (56694718, 71838208))
('chr13', (27185654, 39682032))
```

Is that not what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried updating my code to your suggestion but haven't had any joy. See the question update for more details. :)

Comment: Have updated the answer; Let me know if it works for you. If I may, can I ask a specific question? Bioinformatically, what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to find out if one of your read/cluster of reads is within a GTF record?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something like

```
def region_to_variant_location_match(search_Variants, database_Variants):
    '''Take dictionaries for search_Variants and database_Variants as input.
    Match variants in database_Variants to regions within search_Variants.
    Return matches as a nested dictionary.'''
    return {
        record[0]: record[1]
        for record, lookup in zip(
            database_Variants.items(),
            search_Variants.items()
        )
        if (
            record[1]['Chr'] == lookup[1]['Chr'] and 
            lookup[1]['Start'] <= record[1]['Start'] <= lookup[1]['End']
        )
    }
```

Note that if you were using Python 2.7 or lower (instead of Python 3), you would do `iteritems()` instead of `items()` and `itertools.izip()` instead of `zip`, and if you were using less than 2.6, you would need to switch to a generator comprehension being passed to `dict()` instead of a `dict` comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't want to work for me unfortunately (I realise I may have to adapt it). I get 'ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack' from the 'for' clause. Any ideas?

Comment: @s_boardman: edited to correct the issue you noted--the tuples weren't `chain`ing properly. Apparently the quick sample I'd done was too abstracted from what needed doing, and `itertools.chain` wasn't behaving as desired. This is hopefully still reasonably clear and closer to desired behavior.